acknowledgments in publications
Some people write acknowledgments in publications stating clearly whose funding belongs to whom, like A thanks this funding and B thanks that funding. Why don't they just put all funding together without stating individual authors and write it as: we thank all funding. Is there any difference between these approaches?

What exactly are you wondering about? Clearly stating which funding belongs to whom communicates that whereas a blanket statement does not. (As the question basically already says itself. )

is it good to just thank all funding without stating individual authors

Lots of funding agency require acknowledgments, sometimes in specific form that one cannot change so to preserve uniformity of recognition; it is a condition of the grant that you acknowledge them in a specific way.  For instance, some funding agencies require that you write the grant number or project number.
It is also perfectly possible (and also happens not infrequently) to have one author funded from several sources because different agencies have different rules on the use of funds.  Thus, the visit of person A to person B might be funded from a different pot than the research program of person A.  There might be some special program that provides access to — say — computing resources or data sets.
From an accountability perspective (public or private), clarity and specificity are essential for people to understand the mission of a funding agency, and it would be misleading to suggest that all researchers involved have received support from this or that organization.  If some funding is targeted to women, does it make sense to suggest that men may have received funding by lumping all acknowledgements together?  What if the funding is targeted to young scholars but there are senior and junior researchers on the project?  What is there are two young scholars but only one of them is funded by given agency?

Different funding sources have different requirements for grant acknowledgments. For example, the Office of Basic Energy Sciences (BES) at the US Department of Energy funds so-called Energy Frontier Research Centers (EFRC) for which it provides a detailed document about "Acknowledgments of Support". This document includes the following excerpts requiring a high degree of specificity:

The practice of simply presenting a list of supporting agencies in a shared acknowledgement is not acceptable because it is impossible to discern the research BES funded with respect to research funded by other agencies. In addition, this type of acknowledgement suggests that there could be overlap in the work supported by federal agencies, which would be illegal.


BES recognizes that some publications may bring together results from several projects, as well as from other collaborators, and may include work funded by other funding agencies. In cases where research was supported by multiple programs or agencies, the acknowledgement sections should explicitly delineate which parts of the reported research were specifically supported by the EFRC as well as the other funding sources.


As you brought up DOE, I thought I would point out that we have had a PI get called out by DOE specifically for including all his funding sources.  This PI was basically told, do not do this again.  They also want to know the relative proportion of DOE funding, so they suggested saying things like "mostly funded by DOE" or something like this to show that it is the main reason the paper was published.  This obviously feels different than listing 10 funding sources on the paper, which diminishes their role.  I've not seen any other agency reach out like this before.

@yourfriendlyresearchadmin interesting.  At the other end, I was on a grant committee (not DOE) where one reason (of many) for sinking the proposal was the team had a history of not properly acknowledging funding sources.

@ZeroTheHero -- we have a lot of PIs, even at the R01 I work for, who do not properly acknowledge funding, and I don't understand why.  I keep trying to remind them, "don't you want this to go on your RPPR?"  I wish more emphasis was made on this behavior in grad school.  Some PIs are rockstars on the topic, and others just don't get it.  There's no obvious pattern where I can figure out why it's confusing to a large swath of researchers.

They're likely identifying which money funded which author. A is thanking the funding that paid A. B is thanking the funding that paid B.

This answer looks a restatement of my question without answering?

@feynman If they thank all funding together, then it is not possible to identify which funding paid who from the acknowledgement/disclosure.

"it is not possible to identify which funding paid who from the acknowledgement/disclosure" why does this matter?

@feynman Why wouldn't it?

As an additional argument: The usual form helps to judge conflict of interests.
Imagine a paper for a clinical study of some new drug with three authors. One author works for the company hoping to sell the drug, one has a grant from NIH, one from NHS. One author  might be motivated to present results in favor for his employer. The others two have grants and might have corrected overly optimistic statements.
If they just thanked the three sources of funding, a reader could not be sure whether everybody got funding from the drug company.

Could you please explain this? If I know which of the authors was funded by which grant, how would that help me to know if the overly optimistic statement in the paper is due to a conflict of interests on the part of one of the authors? Doesn't it assume that different parts of the paper are written by different people and clearly separated? Or do you assume that the presence of a co-author who is not directly funded by a pharmaceutical company would somehow eliminate or at least "dilute" the bias of the other co-author(s)? I don't think it works that way.

Authors discuss and review the content of the paper. If one is overly optimistic and stretching above and beyond scientific arguments, co-authors discuss this. If they are funded by an independent source, such behavior is even more likely to happen.

This is just one possible scenario, which is based on the assumption that all authors are willing to follow the principles of good scientific practice and are open to criticism. In such situations, problems are not expected. This scenario does not work in the case of a deliberate misconduct. Say, author A funded by X used equipment owned by author B who is funded by Y. Author B is biased and would not accept the criticism. Author A knows that criticizing B would deprive him of the possibility to use his equipment. So he has a conflict of interests despite not being funded directly by Y.

Formally this should not make any difference. It is only important to mention all funding sources. However, when there are too many, it may look confusing. Someone may wonder why so many different grants are funding a single research project. Therefore as long as the journal allows it, adding detail can do no harm, just like with author contributions.
P.S. For clarity: Adding funding sources to acknowledgements serves one very practical purpose, which you seem to overlook entirely. They are processed by bibliometric databases so that you can search WebOfScience or similar bibliometric portals for papers resulting from a particular grant. This is what is actually done by referees who are reviewing new grant applications (especially continuation proposals) or evaluate candidates for faculty positions. As long as bibliometric databases are unable to break this information down by author, adding it to the paper is of very limited use. That is why I said that it would do no harm, but for purposes of statistics it makes little difference and is therefore not (formally) required. Funding agencies know anyway whom a particular grant belongs to and who of the authors specifically benefits from it. More often than not this information is also made public.
You should also be aware that the allocation of grants to authors is not always unambiguous. For example, I may be the only applicant for a grant, but my PhD student may be funded by that grant, perhaps only partially (often without even knowing that the grant exists). Another postdoc working in another lab and funded by another professor's grant could benefit from doing some measurements in my lab using equipment bought with my grant. Should they be listed on my grant as well? Should I be listed on the other professor's grant because I benefit from his postdoc doing work in my lab for our joint paper? In a large collaboration, this can get so entangled that splitting the funding contributions by author becomes impossible or too difficult to explain.

It certainly can make a formal difference in the sense that some funding agencies require specificity in the acknowledgements.

This is not good advice.  In some cases multiple funding sources are truly in play, but by taking the lazy approach and listing all funding, you violate individual sponsored award terms and conditions.  Additionally, US federal law states that they cannot fund the same research twice.  If you suggest there is so much overlap in your funding, then it appears you may be acquiring funding without fully disclosing on your current and pending documents, which require overlap statements.  This is actually a very big deal, and if DOJ thinks a PI is scamming the government, they could prosecute.

It is quite normal to have multiple funding sources in one paper, which does not imply double funding. The paper may report data obtained in different labs using different techniques that were funded by their different grants. Therefore it is a good idea to specify which author was funded by which grant.

My answer is not advice. It is a de facto standard (at least in my field) to list all funding sources in the acknowledgements, and only a minority of papers would provide details. This is due to the requirement of funding agencies that their grants be acknowledged. There is no formal requirement to break this down by author, whether you like it or not. I wrote that doing this is actually good practice. Still, at the end of the day this information is lost anyway in any bibliometric database such as WebOfScience or alike.
